# How does Bouncy Castle API know which key to encrypt with?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, openpgp

I'm curious about the Bouncy Castle API process for handling multiple public keys to encrypt data. For example, if i have 3 different clients that would like me to encrypt data and send to them using their public key for encryption, if i label each clients public key respectively - how does bouncy castle determine that client 1 should be encrypted with public key 1 and not public key 3 (which would be the public key for client 3)?

it would seem from a decrpytion standpoint, that publicKeyEncryptedData has a keyID tag attached with it that can be used to look up the corresponding private key, but i dont understand how it chooses the correct key to encrypt with.

Comment: Bouncy castle is open source, so you could answer your question by debugging your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't. You have to specify all recipients (i.e. certificates to use for encryption). When you are doing encryption using PKCS#7 the process is:

- Generate random symmetric key (i.e. AES256)
- encrypt data with symmetric key
- encrypt symmetric key with public key of the recipient (if X recipients should be able to decrypt then encrypt the symmetric key X-times)
- put it all together in PKCS#7 (encrypted symmetric key is put in a structure with some identification of the recipient. Usually it is serial number and issuer DN of the certificate which was used for encryption of symmetric key)

Decryption process is:

- find recipient able to decrypt the message. PKCS#7 contains serial numbers and issuer DNs of all recipients who should be able to decrypt. Now look in crypto store for a certificate with serial number and issuer DN that has a corresponding private key. It does not matter which private key will be used if you have all recipients private keys in crypto store.
- use private key to decrypt symmetric key used in the encryption process
- use symmetric key to decrypt data